# How to find the shortest path of length k from a vertex in a weighted graph?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, shortest-path

Is there an algorithm to find, in a complete weighted graph, from a vertex the shortest path of **length k** ?

The Djikstra algorithm does not seem to me to be played for this problem, since we can not choose the size of the path.

Does it have an algorithm to solve this problem? Could a variant of Djikstra's algorithm do the trick?

For example, for the following graph ([Graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkbrj.png)). 
With k = 3, for the vertex A, we would them a path like A-E-D-C, with a weigth of 324. That is the path with the minimum weight.

Comment: Does it have to be exactly `k`? or can it be less than 'k'?

Comment: The path must be exactly k.

Comment: @AlpHa03 then why call it a shortest path then?

Comment: If `k` is fixed, then what do you mean by "length" and "shortest"?

Comment: I don't think there is some clever DP algorithm like Dijkstra's here since depending on the k you may want to make a lot of repeat circuits. Best bet would to be a BFS style search and prune when you get a weight larger than k

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Because it is the shortest of all paths with k vertex

Comment: How are you measuring shortest, by edges traversed or by the sum of weight along those edges?

Comment: @Bergi "length" is the number of vertex and "shortest" is the minimum weight of the path

Comment: @MitchelPaulin the shortest is the sum of weigth along those edges and length is the number of vertex

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Thank you I will do some research in this direction.

Comment: Can the answer-path contain the same node multiple times? Like A-B-A-C?

Comment: @trincot No, the path must contain only single vertex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the graph is indeed **complete** like you mentioned in the question then this is an instance of the subset sum problem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Since a **complete** graph lets you jump from any node to any node at any time the structure of the graph does not matter, just the weights. The problem is **NP-complete** though so there is no efficient way to do this

If the graph is not complete then the Bergi's answer is necessary. An expensive BFS is your only choice

Comment: I think it would Subset Sum if the *nodes* had weights.  But here the *edges* have weights, so the choice of which vertex to move to constrains the weights available to add at the next step.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think Dijakstra would do well. You are not looking for getting to each node with the shortest distance, you are looking to get *anywhere* (that is `k` hops from your origin) with the minimum distance.

You can use a breadth-first or depth-first graph traversal instead, and just find the minimum distance in the search tree bounded by `k`. You can use [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) to optimise the tree search.

Comment: While this is correct for a generic graph OP's graph is complete so you can make the problem a bit simpler

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Oops, didn't notice that. So upvoted your answer anyway. I also didn't think of pruning the BFS, like you mentioned in a comment.

Comment: If you don't prune you would have infinite recursion

Comment: @MitchelPaulin I meant to stop the recursion at level `k`? Maybe I misunderstood what you meant by "pruning". Updated my answer.

Comment: But if I use a breadth-first or depth-first algorithm, nothing assures me that in the tree I find a path of length k ? There could be one but not necessarily.

Comment: @AlpHa03 Of course, if your graph is too small, there is no such path and the algorithm will be able to come up with "no result".